# How to package a python program

Tags: python

Im new to python programming.Im writing a simple command line based twitter app,and i have to use external libraries like simplejson,tweepy etc.
Is there a way i can package my python program to include these libraries as well,so that when i distribute this program, the user doesnt have to install the required libraries first himself ?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will search for modules in the current directory, so you can just package the libraries along in a subdirectory. For example, if `myprogram.py` use the `foo` package:

```
import foo
```

this means that there's either

- a `foo.py` on your Python path; put it into the same directory as `myprogram.py`, or
- a directory `foo` on your Python path which contains a module `__init__.py`; put the entire directory (`.py` files only, no need for `.pyc` files) into the same directory as `myprogram.py`.

Of course, have a look at the licenses first to check whether they allow redistribution with your program in this manner.