# Include External Libraries in Packaged Python Application

Tags: python

I have just picked up Python to develop a tool and I am so far really enjoying the language, however have one issue I am not entirely sure how to solve.

I am looking to use a few external libraries in my project, at the moment cherryPy and Cheetah however I am not sure how to package up my application so that these libraries are included. Coming from a .NET world the compiler used to do pretty much everything for me.

Have done a bit of googling but have not been able to find any solution, so I must be missing something fundamental. Is this something I need to configure distutils for? Do I need to copy the libs in to my application folder structure anywhere? Both?

Appreciate any advice please. :)

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442886/how-to-package-a-python-program

Comment: Are you asking about packaging a Python application for Windows?  Or cross-platform?

Comment: Hi P-T, the difference I have with that question is that I am wanting to package external libraries provided bvy others, with my application.

Comment: retracile - I want to package up so that all of my code is distributable together and that the required external libraries are kept with the code. 

I will eventually want to package for Linux/Mac, not really interested in Windows.

Comment: The linked duplicate specifically mentions including third-party libraries. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: @JordanWindebank you're going to want to tag people as i did; otherwise they won't get a notificatin

Comment: Might want to check this, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-pythonpackaging/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking is how to create what Python calls a [Built Distribution](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html).  This can be done with [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html) and it *is* tedious.  And again I'm guessing at the question, but I think you'd benefit from the docs about [describing extension modules](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#describing-extension-modules).

Besides that, I don't think a broad answer would be complete without pointing at [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) -- utilities to create standalone executables for Windows and OS X, respectively.